# J - How to delete a reference?

Tags: j

I am currently trying to build and delete references in j805. By:

```
jd 'ref tableA colA tableB colB'
```

I can create references. But I have problems when trying to delete it. I tried:

```
jd 'drop ref tableA colA tableB colB'
jd 'dropdynamic ref tableA colA tableB colB'
jd 'delete ref tableA colA tableB colB'
```

Or even the code in j804:

```
jd 'dropdynamic reference tableA colA tableB colB'
```

But those lines of code did not work. Anyone gets an idea how to delete the references? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jd release 4.1 simplified links between database tables (refs). The following answers your question assuming 4.1.

```
     jd'list version'
4.1
   jd'ref f a g b'
   jd'info ref'
┌─────┬───────────┐
│table│column     │
├─────┼───────────┤
│f    │jdref_a_g_b│
└─────┴───────────┘
   jd'dropcol f jdref_a_g_b'
```